# Add Scrollbars to a Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

How does one get scrollbars on a `TextBox`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` properties are used to set horizontal and vertical scroll bars of a TextBox, The ScrollBarVisibility enumeration has four values – `Disabled`, `Auto`, `Hidden`, and `Visible`.

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox"
         Width="300" Height="150"
         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
         TextWrapping="Wrap" >           
</TextBox>
```